# How to block a specific page (and not the whole website) in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, blocking

I've tried the Google Chrome extensions BlockSite, StayFocusd, Site Blocker, but they all block whole websites. I'd like to block the main homepage of YouTube while letting me go to specific videos/pages. Is it possible with any of these extensions or other ones?

StayFocusd has an option where it says "leave off the www. before a website to block the whole website," but even so, when I add www.youtube.com to the blocked list, it blocks every "subpage" from YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

AdBlock is an extension that allows you to hide ads/frames/sidebars of a website. It won't block the youtube homepage in the way that StayFocusd would, but it can be configured to present you with a blank homepage with no recommended videos.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `https://www.youtube.com/` to the `Blocked Sites` list and `https://youtube.com/*` to `Allowed Sites` in StayFocusd works for me in the current version.

Another solution - with uBlock Origin, you can add this to the `My filters` section:

```
||youtube.com^|$document
```

That way only the homepage is blocked.

You can then disable/enable uBlock on the domain by pressing the "shutdown" icon in extension menu, although this is not the best solution if uBlock Origin is your adblock of choice normally, since you enable ads in that case too then.